# DRF. Trying to create a record that requires an instance of another DB object, and keep getting "int() argument must be a string..."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and DRF and I'm really struggling with something.

I'm attempting to create a record in a table that has a foreign key. We'll say the models looks like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  foo_id = models.IntegerField(
    primary_key=True,
  )
  name = models.CharField(
    max_length=256,
  )

class Bar(models.Model):
  bar_id = models.CharField(
    primary_key=True,
    max_length=256
  )
  name = models.CharField(
    max_length=256,
  )
  foo = models.ForeignKey(
    Foo,
    models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='rel',
  )
```

When I try this:

```
Bar.objects.create(
  bar_id = "A1",
  name = "John",
  foo = 5
)
```

I get the error that I would expect:

```
Cannot assign "5": "Bar.foo" must be a "Foo" instance.
```

But if I try:

```
Bar.objects.create(
  bar_id = "A1",
  name = "John",
  foo = Foo.objects.get(foo_id=7)
)
```

I get:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Foo'
```

Really don't understand as I'm sure I've created records like this elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bar.objects.create(
  bar_id = "A1",
  name = "John",
  foo_id = 7
)
```

or this:

```
bar = Bar(bar_id="A1", name="John")
bar.foo_id = 7
bar.save()
```

Comment: But it's a foreign key relationship, so the foo_id needs to be an instance of an object from the Foo table, that's the point. And your first suggestion is identical to the one used in my question.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, I see. No, it still doesn't work. I think that would give me an error about the key rather than the value but, no, it doesn't work.

Comment: what error do you get ? it should work

Comment: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Foo'

Comment: no i am saying when you add `foo_id` like i did then what error you get while creating bar object ?

Comment: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Foo'. So, as I suggested, it likes 'foo_id'. What it doesn't like is the value that I am assigning to 'foo_id'.

Comment: Thank you. It was more an issue with my serializer. After changing a few things and using your save() method, it works.

Answer (score 0):

first you should null=True when you are using SET_NUll

```
   foo = models.ForeignKey(
    Foo,
    models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    related_name='rel',   )
```

Secound you can use below approaches

```
Bar.objects.create(
      bar_id = "A1",
      name = "John",
      foo_id = 5
    )
```

and your secound approach is correct

```
Bar.objects.create(
  bar_id = "A1",
  name = "John",
  foo = Foo.objects.get(foo_id=7)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. If it's correct, can you tell me why it's not working and why I get the error detailed?

Comment: because you didn't put null=True

Comment: I have null=True. I was keeping the model descriptions brief, apologies.

Comment: i tested your code and your secound approach is correct
you probably missing something idk

Comment: are you sure you run migrate and makemigrations?